# Unexpected values (values being added) to column/output generated/formatted incorrectly from SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb, heidisql

```
CREATE TABLE `flatpack_apn` (
    `FlatpackID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    `Colour` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Type` ENUM('Office','Kitchen','Bedroom','General') NOT NULL,
    `UnitPrice` DECIMAL(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`FlatpackID`)
)
COLLATE='hp8_english_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=12
;
```

Above is the table I have.

I am asked to:

List flatpack details in the format: FlatpackName (Type)-UnitPrice with 
heading “Flatpack”.

To do so, I used:

```
SELECT CONCAT ('FlatpackName'+ '('+Type+ ')' +'-'+UnitPrice) 
FROM coursework.flatpack_apn;
```

However, despite the fact that the query runs without errors, the only output I get is:

```
76
76
16
32.2
48.2
68.2
129
26
26
26
226
```

Here is a picture of the sample data I have populated my table with.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/QYFqsL1]

So it would appear then that my query has returned only the unitprices, and then added to the existing values (I don't know why this has occurred).

How can I ensure that I am able to format and output the data properly?

Comment: what is the expected output you are trying to get?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using commas (`,`) instead of plus signs (`+`) inside the `CONCAT()`?

Comment: What's the database? PostgreSQL, DB2, Sybase, H2, etc.

Comment: At present, I am HeidiSQL.

Comment: HeidiSQL is a GUI client that supports multiple RDBMS products. That doesn't answer @TheImpaler's question.

Comment: But the use of `ENGINE=InnoDB` and back-ticks indicates you are using either MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: Yes, I am using MariaDB, with the HeidiSQL that was downloaded as part of the MariaDb package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `+` on strings . .. it doesn't make sense to add them.  When you do so, leading digits are turned into a number, so `'FlatpackName'` becomes `0`.

You want commas instead:

```
SELECT CONCAT('FlatpackName', '(', Type,  ')', '-', UnitPrice)
```

Comment: `+` is used for string concatenation in Microsoft SQL Server, but not other databases. The OP is clearly using MySQL or MariaDB.